# get average of times that take job finish in for loop shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Here is my first shell script

```
 #!/bin/bash
 COUNTER=0
 while [  $COUNTER -lt 10000 ]; do
        date;
     time wget -q 'http://exmple.com/' > /dev/null | grep real;
     sleep 3;
     let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
 done
 echo ${COUNTER} Request Sent\n
 Average Response Time is :
```

this script download page content and calculate time of page response

i need to store Real parameter and calculate average of it

the output of script is something like that

```
Tue Oct 25 22:43:36 
real    0m13.275s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.008s
```

So my problems are :

- How can i add some jobs (like echo ${COUNTER} ) after pressing crtl+c (stopping script)
- How can i store value of "real" in seconds // sometimes page response goes to minutes , so basically need some time convert function (?)

i tried to solve the problems but as i mentioned i am training shell script

Comment: This is too many issues in one Q. You need to prioritze what is important. I don't see you storing the output from `time` so you can add it  up. I would test to see if `time while [  $COUNTER -lt 10000 ]; do .... ; done` will work. Then you have one value for the whole process. Figure out your other issues using this value. If you really need indvidual times added up, then you're in a better place to fix that later. Good luck.

Comment: A C-style loop will eliminate the need to increment `COUNTER` manually within the loop (e.g. time `for ((COUNTER = 0; COUNTER < 10000; COUNTER++)); do ... done` (personally a loop variable `i` sure cuts down on typing...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "How many runs would you like to perform?"
read limit
total_time=0
counter=1
while [ ${counter} -le ${limit} ]
do
        date
        run_time=`(time -p wget -qO- http://exmple.com/) 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep real | awk '{print $2}'`
        echo "Run ${counter} completed in ${run_time} seconds"
        total_time=$(bc<<<"${total_time}+${run_time}")
        if [ ${counter} -ne ${limit} ]
        then
                sleep 3
                let counter=counter+1
        fi
done
avg=$(printf "%.3f" "$(bc -l <<<"${total_time}/${limit}")")
echo "${counter} requests were sent taking ${total_time} seconds"
echo "Average response time was : ${avg} seconds"
```

Above is a modified script to perform the operations you requested, with a couple modifications

- Added a question then input to ask how many runs to make each time, instead of a static number
- Print out total time for runs and then average per run in 3 decimal places
- Skip sleeping if it's the last run

You'll notice we use `bc` instead of `let` for a couple math lines.  The `bc` command allows the use of decimal places.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html

To get the value in seconds I had to use `awk` to separate the value from the title 'real' in the line.  Then you can do the math on the number value.

One other thing I noticed in your initial script.  You used both ways of displaying a variable:

`$COUNTER` and `${COUNTER}`

While both are legitimate, I got into the habit of always encapsulating my variables, it makes things easier when you want to add to the end of it.

For example let's say I have a number defined (`NUM=7`), but want to display it times 10.  If I don't encapsulate `echo $NUM0` then I get an error because the variable `$NUM0` wasn't defined.  But if I encapsulate `echo ${NUM}0` will display an output of `70`.

All of this results in a final output as below

```
How many runs would you like to perform?
5
Tue Oct 25 16:02:58 MST 2016
Run 1 completed in 0.09 seconds
Tue Oct 25 16:03:01 MST 2016
Run 2 completed in 0.08 seconds
Tue Oct 25 16:03:05 MST 2016
Run 3 completed in 0.07 seconds
Tue Oct 25 16:03:08 MST 2016
Run 4 completed in 0.09 seconds
Tue Oct 25 16:03:11 MST 2016
Run 5 completed in 0.08 seconds
5 requests sent taking .41 seconds
Average response time was : 0.08 seconds
```

Please let me know if you have any other questions about the script.

Comment: It's kind of hard to find something slower than calling `bc` within a loop, but then again, that's just time added to the average.

Comment: @Stephan sorry i know it's long time from this post , but when i try to run it i got `(standard_in) 1: syntax error`  on verbose also when request count is finished it's going to loop

Comment: @user3325376 Are you using the exact code I put up?  I tested prior to posting.

Comment: @Stephan yes, the exact code, it's going in loop when job finished and never show average response part

Comment: @user3325376 Could you post the whole output of the script? Including the prompts and responses?

Comment: @Stephan sure, the problem is after run checks finished not showing result and going to infinite loop
`# ./ok.sh
How many runs would you like to perform?
2
Mon Jan 23 21:53:51 EST 2017
Run 1 completed in 0.13 seconds
Mon Jan 23 21:53:54 EST 2017
Run 2 completed in 0.17 seconds
############LOOP STARTING#########
Mon Jan 23 21:53:54 EST 2017
Run 2 completed in 0.15 seconds
Mon Jan 23 21:53:55 EST 2017
Run 2 completed in 0.19 seconds
Mon Jan 23 21:53:55 EST 2017
Run 2 completed in 0.13 seconds
Mon Jan 23 21:53:55 EST 2017
....`

Comment: You've clearly modified the code, in the example here I don't have any point where it says 'LOOP STARTING'.  Can you post your current version, all of it to a pastebin or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can record a reasonably precise time with e.g.

```
t1=$(date +%s.%N)
wget ...
t2=$(date +%s.%N)
diff=$(($t2-$t1))
```

For doing stuff after Ctrl+C, which is really a `SIGINT` signal, read up about the `trap` builtin.

Comment: Stuff the loop in between `t1` and `t2` and divide by `COUNTER` looks like a complete solution. (except for the manual `sleep`, which you could eliminate by subtracting `$((COUNTER * 3))` from the total time)